# onContextItemSelected not called using a Dialog with a ListView

Tags: android, listview, menu, dialog

I'm creating a simple dialog with a ListView on it. I want to be able to access a context menu on it. Here's the basic code I've:

```
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);
  dialog.setTitle("Contact");
  ListView  lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView);  Cursor cursor = db.readData();
                                   String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_contacts, DatabaseHandler.KEY_number};
                                         int[] to = new int[]{R.id.contacts, R.id.number};
                                         @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                                         final
                                         SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Home.this, R.layout.show, cursor, from, to);
                                         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                         lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

here the method onCreateContextMenu:

```
   @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_context, menu);

}
```

And finally I override the onContextItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.call:
            Toast.makeText(this,"call" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.sms:
            Toast.makeText(this,"sms" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.delete:
            Toast.makeText(this,"delete" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I've tried also to override setOnMenuItemClickListener() inside onContextItemSelected()

but my problem still is not solved :( Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Item using this method

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      Object listItem = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
   } 
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "list."    you mean listview "lv" ?